# Is there a way to create a second console to output to in .NET when writing a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console

Is there a way to create a second console to output to in .NET when writing a console application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, you could start a new cmd.exe process and use stdio and stdout to send and recieve data.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process p = Process.Start(psi);

StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;

sw.WriteLine("Hello world!");
sr.Close();
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I can't get this to work either. The process gets started because I can see it in Task Manager, but the console window never appears, regardless of what I set the `CreateNoWindow` and `WindowStyle` properties of the ProcessStartInfo object to. Maybe it's related to permissions on Windows 7?

Comment: The window doesn't show for me either, same as @StevenRands

Comment: What you are doing here is to start cmd.exe which is a command line interpreter. What would be more useful is to start a process that creates a console and redirect input (keyboard) to output (screen).

Answer (score 4):

The following fires off an application-dependent number of console windows and stores the amount and parameters for the console inside a String Dictionary that is then looped to generate the required amount of spawned console apps. You would only need the process stuff if only spawning one of course.

```
//Start looping dic recs and firing console
foreach (DictionaryEntry tests in steps)
{
    try
    {
        Process runCmd = new Process();
        runCmd.StartInfo.FileName = CONSOLE_NAME;
        runCmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        runCmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        runCmd.StartInfo.Arguments = tests.Value.ToString();

        if (cbShowConsole.Checked)
        {
            runCmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            runCmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            runCmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            runCmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
        }
        runCmd.Start();                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string t1 = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Note this is intended either to run hidden (CreateNoWindow) or visible.

Comment: Where and how is `CONSOLE_NAME` defined?

Comment: However you want it to be. It could be a string CONSOLE_NAME = **** or it could be a string in the steps Dictionary being looped in the above example. For microsofts definition see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score -7):

A single console is attached to any given process. So in short you can not. But there are ways to "fake it"