# Open a new console application while running the existing console app)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to create a second console to output to in .NET when writing a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-con)

How to open a new console application (2) while running the existing console app (1)?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
       Console.WriteLine("success"); 

       //how to close this console          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Due To: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //code for opening the second console....(is that passible)
        //how to close this console
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to launch a second process, or do you have something more in mind?

Comment: just want to open second console application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `Process` Class

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

Edit: Something like that, but you have to notice that this will create a new instance of the application every time the previous version closed! (*is that what you want?*)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Due To: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //code for opening the second console....(is that passible)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ConsoleApplication15.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls expline me deeper...

Comment: in this case, it will be closed automatically after launching the second instance. p.s.: putting `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ConsoleApplication15.exe");
` inside  `finally` block will create the second instance no matter what happened, anyway, you can use the `return;` keyword inside the `static main` method to close your application