# What is the Console path in C#?

Tags: c#, path, console-application

I am trying to show text in a console launched from the click button. I think I need to input the console's path where I have put the question marks Process.Start("????"). How do I find the console path?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("????");
        Console.WriteLine("Adam");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not doing what you think it does. `Console.WriteLine` will not write to a command line process you start with `Process.Start`. Instead it will write to the console of your application - which is not existing in your case because you have a WinForms application. Please explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. I think I need to go and read up on this a bit more. Do I need to save a console operation (under/with console application) and then access that operation/process from windows forms applications through the click button?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Do you just want a handy console to write a bunch of messages to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is grab the console from the windows API.  This will create a new instance of a console application that can output and read etc.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int FreeConsole();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int alloc = AllocConsole(); // Grab a new console to write to
        if (alloc != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
            return;
            }
        Console.WriteLine("test");

        Console.WriteLine("Adam");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        // Do other funky stuff

        // When done
        FreeConsole();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice example how to do this: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/130369-command-prompt-use-within-csharp-class-file.html#post973331

Code:

```
string returnvalue = "";

// Starts the new process as command prompt
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
// Makes it so the command prompt window does appear
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process process = Process.Start(info))
{
    StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;
    StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;

    // This for loop could be used if you had a string[] commands where each string in commands
    // is it's own command to write to the prompt. I chose to hardcode mine in.
    //foreach (string command in commands)
    //{
    //    sw.WriteLine(command);
    //}
    sw.WriteLine("cd " + processPath);
    sw.WriteLine("perl process.pl");

    sw.Close();
    returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

return returnvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the application `cmd.exe`. But using `Controle.WriteLine` won't write to that console and `Console.ReadLine` won't read from that console. You'll have to redirect the input and output streams of the process to interact with the console application started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class that wraps AllocConsole():

```
/// <summary>Simple class to allow creation and destruction of Consoles.</summary>

public static class ConsoleManager
{
    #region public static Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a console output window, if one doesn't already exist.
    /// This window will receive all outputs from System.Console.Write()
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// 0 if successful, else the Windows API error code from Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>See the AllocConsole() function in the Windows API for full details.</remarks>

    public static int Create()
    {
        if (AllocConsole())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Destroys the console window, if it exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// 0 if successful, else the Windows API error code from Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>See the FreeConsole() function in the Windows API for full details.</remarks>

    public static int Destroy()
    {
        if (FreeConsole())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
    }

    #endregion  // public static Methods

    #region Private PInvokes

    [SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Security", "CA2118:ReviewSuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityUsage" ), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();


    [SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Security", "CA2118:ReviewSuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityUsage" ), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();

    #endregion  // Private PInvokes
}
```

Just call ConsoleManager.Create() and then you should be able to do Console.WriteLine().

Comment: Ok, I'm editing my reply with something that will hopefully help!

Answer (score 1):

You should have **two** projects. The first one is your *Windows applications* with all it's functionalities and the other one should be a project with type "*Console Application*". Then you should execute the output of the second project (Your Console application.exe) in the click event of the button.

The problem is that you don't have the thing to call "`Console.WriteLine`" that way. Simply it doesn't work. My recommendation is to use .NET Remoting to do staffs between two different projects.

**.NET Remoting IPC:**

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/remoting/article.php/c9251/NET-Remoting-Using-a-New-IPC-Channel.htm

Hope it helps!