# Creating a terminal in C# WinForms program

Tags: c#, winforms, console, command-line-interface, pty

I'd like to build a terminal into a C# WinForms application, for use with communicating over serial ports, a terminal over the network, or any other kind of command/response mechanism.

I thought the easiest way would be to open a Windows console and re-direct the stdin, stdout, and stderr streams to TextStreams in my program, but I can't find an obvious way to do this. I don't want to use System.Console and get it mixed up with other error/debug messages.

Even better is if I can embed the console as a control on the WinForm.

Are either of these solutions possible without any 3rd party libraries or enormous amounts of coding?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use `System.Console`? `System.Console` is _the_ way to interact with the console in C#...

Comment: System.Console is intrinsically linked with my application - you can only have one, and it looks like you can't close it once you've opened it. I want something on its own, and that I can create more than one of.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. In that case, there's a few ways you can go about this - probably the best would be the way you suggested with the WinForm windows. You can actually create multiple instances of the console (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co) question) but I wouldn't recommend it, as it might get a little confusing for the user when console windows open other console windows. I think if you have the WinForms solution, it would be much clearer

Comment: There is already open source projects like this, so why not simply check them out if you don't want to code yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Use this class to access a console from WinForms. 
You will need to allocate a console and save this to a variable for later manipulation. I have included some sample code below that I've used in a past project. You can then call the Console.WriteLine("") method to send text to the window.  Hope this helps!

```
public class ConsoleHelper
{
    public const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates a new console for current process.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

    /// <summary>
    /// Frees the console.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    public const int SW_SHOW = 5;
}
```

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
    void OpenSerialConnection(int portnumber, System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon TrayIcon)
    {
        //Get console window
        handle = ConsoleHelper.GetConsoleWindow();
        if (handle.ToInt32() == 0)
        {
            //Create the console window
            ConsoleHelper.AllocConsole();
        }
        handle = ConsoleHelper.GetConsoleWindow();

        //Show console window
        ConsoleHelper.ShowWindow(handle, ConsoleHelper.SW_SHOW);

        //Remove close button from console window (can only be closed from code now)
        ConsoleHelper.DeleteMenu(ConsoleHelper.GetSystemMenu(ConsoleHelper.GetConsoleWindow(), false), ConsoleHelper.SC_CLOSE, ConsoleHelper.MF_BYCOMMAND);
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = "COM" + portnumber.ToString();
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Form1.BaudRate;
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                TrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Error in " + error.Source.ToString(), "The program encountered an error while trying to open the serial connection. This may be due to closing the program prematurely. Try unplugging your board and restarting the program!", System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Error);
                //Hide console window
                ConsoleHelper.ShowWindow(handle, ConsoleHelper.SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.WriteLine("====CONSOLE OPENED ON (COM PORT " + portnumber.ToString() + ")=======");
        Console.WriteLine("===========BAUD RATE: " + Form1.BaudRate.ToString() + "=============");
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
```