# How do I get console application window in C#?

Tags: c#

I am getting started on C# and installed Microsoft blend for visual studio and my newproject window looks like below.[image: New project window]

I am looking for console application as shown in below screeshot,how do I get it? [image: Console application]

EDIT1:

how do I launch visual studio IDE?

[image: Visualstudio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going along with what everyone else is saying, Visual Studio 2015 COMMUNITY EDITION is free to download and fully featured. Great tool, if anything it has too many uses. I believe it may even have most of the Visual Basic features built in.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx

Comment: I installed using the link you shared,however I dont see an optition to launch IDE,I attached a screenshot of it,can you please help on  how to launch the IDE?

Comment: Did you download the software or just the dev tools? Did you install the IDE yet? It's a pretty big install. It should be outside of the VS tools folder if it is installed. I know from my own experience that if there were any previous VS versions on the machine when you try to install a new version, very strange things can happen...

Answer (score 8):

Use Visual Studio, not Blend, to create a new Console Application.

More info on [Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx) and it's uses.

Answer (score 3):

[Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx) is an interface design tool and therefore can't be used to build console apps... Try [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft Blend Website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296376.aspx):

> Microsoft Expression Blend is a full-featured professional design tool for creating engaging and sophisticated user interfaces for Microsoft Windows

Which a console application is not; is has basically no UI. You should keep on using Visual Studio for console application.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely make the console window appear in almost any application simply by using [Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0) you can also create an arbitrary console by launching one:

[Is there a way to create a second console to output to in .NET when writing a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co)

Legacy Services were default are not [User Interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userinteractive?view=net-5.0) and thus have no console easily viewable..