# How do I make a function be executed in new console?

Tags: c#

How can i make it so my function is executed in a new console?
Basically when the function Function() is called, i want it to be executed in a new console, separate from the main one. Thanks!

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Console 1";
        Function();
    }

    public static void Function()
    {
        // What i want to happen is the function is executed, but in another console(window) that will pop up
        Console.Title = "Console 2";
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, this is a new Console");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a second console to output to in .NET when writing a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697227/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-second-console-to-output-to-in-net-when-writing-a-co)